# Simulate download in Flash CC

Tags: flash, adobe-scout, flash-cc

Is there a way to simulate the download of the swf in Flash CC? I read that this can be done using Scout but can't figure out how.

I want to see if a preloader is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Adobe Scout you need to publish SWF in browser and check it in this way, but IMHO better way might be use something like this: [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) to simulate desirable traffic.
Unfortunately Adobe dropper Bandwith Profiler in FlashCC, which was long time future and really great tool.

Answer (score 0):

we have a trick to check preloader progress. i am describing 
check the code below . here you easily understand that progress is the variable of preloader .

```
var progress = new createjs.Shape(); 
    var progressBellow = new createjs.Shape();
    var txt = new createjs.Text();

    progress.graphics.beginStroke("#280000").drawRect(115,112,100,20);
    progressBellow.graphics.beginStroke("#280000").drawRect(115,112,100,20);
```

now look at  the code below

```
function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.BV_test_procedure_updated220515();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
```

here stage.update means it is updating all the codes of stage . so replace it with

progress.update();

now you are done . you can see your preloader progress. change color width etc. 
after your checking is done . replace again it with 
stage.update .
for better understanding check my link.
http://canvas.byethost11.com/pre/storia3.html
thanks

Comment: you should probably edit your answer and format your code to make it more readable.